# MapActivity class for jelly bean

Tags: android, mapactivity

In a test app I am making for jelly bean it seems that the MapActivity class is throwing a Class not Found exception for my code. As soon as all use of MapActivity is removed the app works.

Here the code. This keeps crashing with Class not found. What Am i doing wrong here?

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public class HomeActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you do not have the `<uses-library>` element in your manifest, or you are running this app on a device or emulator that does not have the Google Maps SDK add-on.

Comment: aaww crap how did i miss that! Thanks a ton!